# Nearest Neighbors in radius via Z-order order curve?

Tags: algorithms, opencl, nearest-neighbors, spatial-data, particle

Given a $M\times M\times M$ 3D cube grid $C$, how can I map the 3D grid-coordinates to 1D coordinates such that **every** cell's nearest neighbors can be represented by a continuous range of corresponding 1D values?

One of the 3D-to-1D mappings could be Z-indexing, but I don't know how to access the neighbors in the way I described above.

---

**Why do I need this:** I'm writing an OpenCL kernel function, that processes particles. In each cell of the grid $C$ can be arbitrary (non-negative :) number of particles. The particles are stored in memory sorted by their cell's id given by the 1D coordinates. And to get the best GPU performance when reading neighbors, I need the neighboring particles to be close in memory (i.e. the 1D coordinates of a grid cells that are close to each other in space are also close).

If you want more of the context, you can see my questions at different SE sites:

- [Nearest Neighbors in CUDA particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646131/nearest-neighbors-in-cuda-particles)
- [Z-order curve — how to query all nearest neighbors?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126269/z-order-curve-how-to-query-all-nearest-neighbors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible, because you cannot order all cells in such a way that neighbors are always in a continuous range. Suppose we try to construct continuous neighbor lists in 3D. Each interior cell $C_i$ has six neighbors, so it should appear six times in a neighbor list. The only way to construct six *continuous* neighbor list is as follows:

- $C_{i-5}$ to $C_{i}$
- $C_{i-4}$ to $C_{i+1}$
- ..
- $C_{i}$ to $C_{i+5}$

These lists contain 11 different cells. However, the left and right $x$-neighbor of $C_i$ already have $5+5+1=11$ different cells in their neighbor list (their only shared neighbor is $C_i$). Because there are also $y$ and $z$-neighbors, we cannot have continuous neighbor lists.

You could instead compute a Morton number $m_i$ for each cell (i.e., use the Z-curve), and then store these numbers in a sorted 1D array. Given any cell, you can compute the Morton number of a neighbor in time $O(1)$, and do a binary search in time $O(\log N)$, where $N$ is the number of cells.

Comment: I've actually thought the same thing, but I was not *completely* sure it's impossible to do without memory sacrifice, so I rather asked.

Comment: FYI, the Morton curve has several large jumps in it, breaking contiguity. The [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) would be a better choice if preserving spatial locality is important.